# How to disable notification on automated sharing google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function addViewer() {     
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const rows = ss.getRange('A2:B').getValues().filter(r=> r[1])
  rows.map(row => DriveApp.getFileById(row[0]).addEditor(row[1]))   
}
```

How to disable notification on the above code? It sents every time I run the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the Advanced Drive API to disable share notifications.

```js
 Drive.Permissions.insert(
   {
     'role': 'writer',
     'type': 'user',
     'value': 'bob@example.com'
   },
   fileId,
   {
     'sendNotificationEmails': 'false'
   });
```

[Source](https://www.labnol.org/code/20101-share-files-google-drive-without-email-notifications)

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the reply, do I just add the above code to my code and change the email address to my account email?

Sorry I am new to google app script.

Comment: You would need to enable Advanced Drive Service in Apps Script.  https://www.labnol.org/static/6a4ee795ba27a4c1774b6eb7ae762657/38c0d/122710.png

Comment: I have added your code and enable Drive Service. However, when I run it, i shows ReferenceError: fileId is not defined. How do I modify the code to solve this error?